# Exception: Deletion of node in Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree

I am getting Exception when running the BST Deletion. Below is my code snippet:

```
Bst::node * Bst::del(node *root, int num)
    {
        if (root == NULL)
        {
            return root;
        }
        else if (num < root->data)
        {
            root->left = del(root->left, num);
        }
        else if (num > root->data)
        {
            root->right = del(root->right, num);
        }
        else
        {
            if (root->left == NULL)
            {
                node * tmp = root;
                root = root->right;
                delete tmp;
            }
            else if (root->right == NULL)
            {
                node * tmp = root;
                root = root->left;
                delete tmp;
            }
            else if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
            {
                delete root;
                root = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                node *tmp = root;
                tmp = findMin(root->right);
                root->data = tmp->data;
                root->right = del(root->right, tmp->data);
            }
        }


        return root;
    }
```

---

```
void Bst::del(int num)
{
     del(root, num);
}
```

Everything works fine when I am deleting the other nodes but when I delete the root node itself then the function `void Bst::del(int num)` gets the garbage value from the function `Bst::node * Bst::del(node *root, int num)`. The error gets resolved when I rewrite my function as

```
void Bst::del(int num)
        {
            root = del(root, num);
        }
```

**Question 1.** Why it works when I delete the middle nodes or any other node except the root node. While debugging I found that even root was getting deleted properly when the function `Bst::node * Bst::del(node *root, int num)`was executing but when the call returned to the `void Bst::del(int num)` then the value of root was not getting retained and was garbage.

**Question 2:** Why the error got fixed when I stored the returned value in variable `root`?

Comment: What kind of BST is this?

Comment: I don't know if there are different kind of BST. I just know in BST left element should be smaller and right should be larger than the root.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe : Skewed BST

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe 1->2->3->4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While deleting a BST node using recursion, you must track the root node, which you're doing correctly as

`root->left = // ...` and `root->right = ...`

However when call reaches to caller after unwinding the stack, the root may get modified ( case when you delete the root itself )

<sub>This *hopefully* answers both of your questions</sub>

Comment: I am not able to visualize the behavior. Everything works fine but only root deletion is creating problem when suppose I have 1,2,3,4 and I am trying to delete 1. I think I need `root=` to hold the returned value. otherwise the `return root; `is going no where..

Comment: Am I kind of making sense?

Comment: @tanz if you write it on paper and do, you'll get it. It basically reaches last else, recurse to right sub-tree

Comment: for input 1,2,3,4 .. If I am trying to delete 1 , which will be root node only..I dont think any recursion will occur. It just goes to the else part and then returns. More like regular function. Please help me here.

Comment: @tanz Well it goes to `findMin` else part replace the `root` with min in right sub-tree i.e. root->right data, now will recurse into this sub-tree and delete the root there, cases as applicable, while unwinding you'll get yo your new `root`, its difficult to explain here, work on notebook and pencil with simple example

Comment: I can understand its difficult to explain here and Thank you so much for trying to explain things to me. But I don't see it going to the findmin part. If you see closely. the if part where I say `root->left == NULL` ., that part will get executed. Because for input 1,2,3,4. left part of 1 will be NULL.

Comment: Even VS Debugger also telling the same thing.

Comment: @tanz I was referring to complete binary tree not your example, so okay with 1->2->3->4 i.e a linked list only your `root=root->right`, and you return root, i.e. your original root got modified, the caller root is now a dangling, you must restore it back, so you should do `root = del(root, num)`

Comment: I kind of got your point. Just tell me one last thing. So even though if I modify root. the caller still holds to the old memory address.. it does not automatically moves to the new root. Since we have only one copy of root still the caller sticks to the old address of root?